# Mesibo - unable to get callbacks on group member addition

Tags: mesibo, groupchat

I am using mesibo for one of the chat apps that I develop. I have listeners for incoming messages, user status change, etc. I am not sure how does mesibo notifies the client when the client is added to a group. I am sure it is a real time communication. I am not getting this particular information in any of the callback.

How does this actually work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

mesibo does not notify your clients. You need to do it from your backend APIs.

1. Your client connects with your backend to add a member to the group
2. Your backend invokes mesibo backend APIs to add a member to the group
3. After adding successfully, your backend can inform all the group members using mesibo backend API https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/backend-api/#message-api

Note that you MUST not use mesibo backend APIs directly from the client, you will get tokenbreach after some time (https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/other/#why-am-i-getting-the-tokenbreach-error).